# ISO-8859-1 from bcp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp, iso-8859-1

I've got data in a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 that I'm trying to output to a CSV file. I then have to import this CSV file into a third-party proprietary system that requires this file to be encoded as ISO-8859-1. In particular, we've got some values with "Š" characters, which is codepoint 8A in Windows-1252, but doesn't appear in ISO-8859-1. I'd like to eliminate/fix these characters (and all of the other 8_ and 9_ codepoints that [don't appear in the ISO standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout)) without munging the files by hand. Doing it entirely in SQL or with a BCP argument would be ideal.

The closest I have been able to get with BCP is using Windows-1252 thusly:

```
bcp tableName out outputFile.csv -c -C 1252 -t, -S server -T
```

Is there a code page I can give BCP to output ISO-8859-1 instead? Or a collation I can apply to the tables? Right now they're collated with `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, but I think that's just our default or was applied somewhat arbitrarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried -C 28591 ? Windows 28591 equals ISO-8859-1